# How to enforce enumeration on a property typed with Enumeration in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

In my block diagram I insert an Enumeration, call it "jointKind", and give it attributes "revolute", "continuous", "prismatic", "fixed" and "floating". Each attribute is Scope=Public, Stereotype=enum. Except for Name, Scope and Stereotype I left other fields (e.g. Type, Alias, Initial) empty.

I then create a block, called it "Robot", and give it a property. That property is typed by "jointKind". However when I chose an initial value I'm given an empty space to type my value.

I should think that when I choose an initial value then the attributes I previously assigned to the enumeration are mad available for me to chose from.

How to enforce enumerations on properties typed by Enumeration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. EA doesn't limit the values you can enter in the initial value, regardless of the type of your property or attribute.

You can use this link to request this as a new feature: https://www.sparxsystems.com/support/forms/feature_request.html

If your **really** want to, you could create an add-in that checks the initial value of an attribute against it's type, and refuse any values that are not part of the enumeration. I'm not sure if it would be worth the effort though.

Comment: Based on your comment I looked around. I saw in your github you have some validation rules. Are they ran as a standalone script? It should be possible for me to write a script to validate all properties typed by Enumeration but preferably that would be part of the Validation rule set...

Comment: Yes, I once played with script based validation, but we ended up building a proper add-in (also open source) that uses SQL based validation rules (much faster). See https://bellekens.com/ea-validator/ alternative would be to use an EA-Matic script to stop the user from entering a wrong value. See https://bellekens.com/ea-matic/